# Changing N in tbl_svysummary to be per 1000 or per 10000

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am using the tbl_svysummary() function from the gtsummary package to create a table for a paper. My N, which I want to show in the header column, is in the millions. I'm trying to figure out how to convert it to be per 1000 or per 10000. For example:

```
data(api, package = "survey")
tbl_svysummary_ex2 <-
  survey::svydesign(id = ~dnum, weights = ~pw, data = apiclus1, fpc = ~fpc) %>%
  tbl_svysummary(by = "both", include = c(api00, stype))
```

Instead of N = 1692 for the No column in this example, I'd like it to be N = 1.692. For larger numbers, let's say N = 12,209,256, I'd want to divide by 10000 and display N = 1220 (per 10,000) or something like that.

I thought I could use modify_header() or modify the .$table_styling$header data.frame directly to do so, but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use `modify_header()`. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.6.3'

data(api, package = "survey")
survey::svydesign(id = ~dnum, weights = ~pw, data = apiclus1, fpc = ~fpc) %>%
  tbl_svysummary(by = "both", include = c(api00, stype)) %>%
  modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}** N={style_number(n, scale = 0.001, digits = 3)}K") %>%
  as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **No** N=1.692K | **Yes** N=4.502K |
| --- | --- | --- |
| api00 | 631 (556, 710) | 654 (551, 722) |
| stype |  |  |
| E | 1,083 (64%) | 3,791 (84%) |
| H | 237 (14%) | 237 (5.3%) |
| M | 372 (22%) | 474 (11%) |

<sup>Created on 2022-12-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>